# validation for time series models

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, cross-validation, validation

Suppose that I have a model $f$ that is trained to predict hourly sales of 100 stores. Each day I retrain the model, and I have 2400 data points each day. Naively, I can split the data into sth like hour 0 - hour 22 as training set, and hour 23 as the validation set. However this does not make too much sense cause the model has not yet seen the pattern on hour 23, how do we expect it to perform well on hour 23? However this seems like the only reasonable approach to validate the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (almost) precisely the correct approach.

> this does not make too much sense cause the model has not yet seen the pattern on hour 23

Indeed. However, it *has* seen sales in hour 22 and in hour 0 at the very beginning of the day. I hope you are [not dummy-coding the hour, but using smooth transformations like Fourier terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/478175/1352), so the model will likely be able to interpolate the cycles.

> how do we expect it to perform well on hour 23?

By using Fourier terms, as above.

Alternatively, collect more data. Especially since you are *re*-fitting the model every day, you apparently have multiple days' worth of data - so just use all of them in a seasonal model. Then you will actually have observed hour 23 from a previous day.

In this setup, it may make sense to use a full day of 24 hours for your evaluation, or run rolling origins for 24 different 1-hour-ahead forecasts. (Or anything in between, like 4 different 6-hour-ahead forecasts.)

Note that hourly data often exhibits [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities), i.e., the pattern in each day will likely differ between weekdays and weekends. [Here are some possible models that can deal with this.](https://dfep.netlify.app/sec-multiple-seasaonality.html)

We have resources on forecasting here: [Resources/books for project on forecasting models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/559908/1352)