Difficulties in tree-based learners for long-horizon / multiple time series forecasting
I'm currently building a massive (20000+ series) framework for forecasting and noticing a struggle when using XGBoost for long horizon (18 month) forecasting, as they are rough for detecting certain forecast patterns that frameworks like NNs are extremely good at. I'm recursively forecasting each step. Due to the computational complexity of the framework, using methods like separate learners for each forecast just isn't feasible from a time complexity standpoint.
I'm feature engineering by using lagged steps, but that's it. Is there anything more other than additional features I can do to improve a tree based learners' performance? Or is this just an issue with long horizon + at scale forecasting

What temporal granularity are your data (daily, monthly, something else)?

@StephanKolassa monthly, and strictly monthly. my data can't be drilled down further than that due to business requirements

OK. Then lags are probably the way to go, especially lags of order 12 to capture yearly seasonality. I assume you already have month dummies? (If you had daily data, I would have recommended feeding in harmonics to capture this seasonality, plus day of week dummies.) Other than that, plus features, I would not know what else to recommend without digging deeper into your data... good luck!

month dummies as in categorizing each month through a dummy variable? so lagged data + dummy columns?

Exactly. Dummies capture the effect of January. Lagged data captures the effect of last January's observation. Two different things!

as bad as it sounds this is completely a revelation to me. i was regressing true values on lagged values n-1 -> n-k where k is the lag number, essentially just making it a MLR problem with no time stamps. do you think performance is prone to improvement with dummies?

Hard to say. I would typically think that ice cream sales in January are low because it's January, not because last January's sales were low. The distinction becomes relevant when last January's sales were atypical. Or if you have a short history and can transfer a "January effect" from a different product, but not a "last January's sales effect", because the product you are forecasting is new and did not have any sales last January. I personally am absolutely not a fan of lags, of any order. But then I'm a retail forecaster, where the data generating process simply does not motivate lags.

Note that if you have daily data, I would not recommend monthly dummies: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/478175/1352. Also, you may find some of our resources on forecasting helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/559908/1352
