Appropriate datatype for cyclical periods (like days of the week and seasons)
I am trying to figure out the best way to encode cyclical time indicators like days of the week and seasons. (Other examples would be day of the month and week of the year, but I'll try to keep this question simple and focused.) To keep this focused, let's consider a regression analysis where the days of the week (Sunday to Saturday) are a predictor (among others) for some outcome variable of interest.
I've looked at similar questions here on Statistics SE, but I cannot find a question that is quite the same. The closest is this one on
What type of data are dates?, but it is asking about chronological dates, not cyclical time periods. (I offered an answer to that question, which distinguishes my question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/648740/81392.)
Let's consider how days of the week (Sunday to Saturday) are typically encoded and the problems I have with these typical approaches:

Integers (e.g., Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, ..., Saturday = 7). The benefit of this encoding is that any regression algorithm can handle it because the days are encoded as numbers and the order of the days is mostly maintained. Not completely, though--there is no indication that Sunday comes after Saturday, which loses important information. The biggest problem, however, with integer encoding is that it assumes that Wednesday (4) is somehow twice as much as Monday (2), which makes no sense. Yet, if you plug this encoding into a regression analysis, that is exactly what the algorithm will assume.

Unordered categories (e.g., "Sunday", "Monday", etc. with no inherent order, e.g., an unordered factor in R). This removes the nonsensical arithmetic operations, which is good, but it completely ignores the fact that Thursday comes later than Sunday and that Monday immediately follows Sunday. Such an encoding throws away the crucial information about order.

Ordered categories (e.g., "Sunday", "Monday", to "Saturday" in strict order, e.g., an ordered factor in R). This is the best of the two previous options: it maintains the same partial order of integers yet it excludes the nonsensical arithmetic operations. However, it still fails at the ends: there is no indication that Sunday comes after Saturday and back again.


(The same arguments apply to other cyclical periods like the four seasons.)
So, my question is: how can cyclical time periods like day of the week be appropriately encoded to maintain both the order of successive days and the cyclical nature where the first strictly follows the last? Given that these periods are evenly spaced (24 hours apart), an interval type would be acceptable, but the cyclicity is what I am missing.

Take a look at my answer in the proposed duplicate: simply keep a running count of your time variable (days or hours), and use sine/cosine transformations with appropriate periodicities as predictors. This is, e.g., how TBATS models multiple seasonalities: "T" stands for "trigonometric". Depending on your seasonal pattern, you can use multiple trigonometric transforms, and you can also keep the running count itself as a predictor to capture a global trend. Plus potentially autoregressive terms, e.g. on residuals from a regression on the trigs.

@StephanKolassa Thanks for the link to a similar question. I affirm that the linked question is along the same lines of what I'm asking. Following the links, I found an answer to another related question which, with its comments, gives me a lot to explore: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/245887/81392. Thanks!
